# how to edit already existing time in spk file to current time?

Tags: sas

I am currently looking to edit a time stamp in spk file using SAS enterprise miner. I would like to change the created date and time to current time in the SAS enterprise miner.

[image: SAS Enterprise Miner screenshot]

Comment: please add your program , what currently you have and what exactly looking to..

Comment: hi, the post has been edited and a screenshot has been attached with the timestamp as shown. i want to change this displayed time to the present time.

Comment: It is not possible to modify this value easily. You will need to contact SAS technical support for additional details on how this value is stored. From my understanding, it is either going to be a permanent attribute in the SAS Metadata Server, or a file system attribute about the project folder that cannot be changed without recreating the folder.